# How to return a string from a function to main()?

Tags: c, string, function, return

I have tried the following code but am getting an **error:conflicting types for fun**.Is there any solution that doesn't require the use of malloc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf("%s",fun());
return 0;
} 

char* fun()
{
static char str[]="Hello";
return str;
}
```

Comment: The closest thing you could do would be to allocate a `char[]` in `main`, give a pointer to it to your function, and then have said function change it. Also, you can't just assign a string literal to a `char[]`, because these are merely pointers to statically allocated string constants. You'd have to use `memcpy()`.

Comment: Why don't you use a `const char*` instead, if you don't want to allocate non-const bytes of a string?

Comment: This is not compliant C code and a modern compiler should complain much earlier..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you have not declared prototype for `fun`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char* fun(void);
int main()
{
   printf("%s",fun());
   return 0;
}

char* fun(void)
{
   static char str[]="Hello";
   return str;
}
```

Comment: It's a subtle C issue, but `char* fun();` is just a declaration, not a prototype. `char* fun(void);` is a prototype (and a declaration).

Comment: @PSkocik Got it.

Comment: However, it is still undefined behaviour because the function returns a dangling pointer.

Comment: @PSkocik Technically `char* fun();` is a declaration without a prototype and `char* fun(void);` is a declaration with a prototype. The prototype is just the `void` part.

Comment: Please be aware that if you're using other's work in your posts, you must provide proper attribution. The plagiarized content has been removed from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

C does not allow an array to be returned from a function, but it does allow a `struct` to be returned from a function. You can define a `struct` type to hold strings in an array, and return such a `struct` from your function to be copied into a receiving `struct`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct String
{
  char body[1024];
};

struct String fun(void);

int main(void)
{
  struct String my_string = fun();
  printf("%s\n", my_string.body);

  return 0;
}

struct String fun(void)
{
  return (struct String){ .body = "Hello" };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
char* fun()
{
    static char str[]="Hello";
    return str;
}
```

str hold base address of your string. (Assume 1000). Now when you **return str**, it'll return only base address.

```
printf("%s",fun());
```

Here you want to print string so you gave %s but this fun return base address of your character array(string) but not string (as you assume).

First, you need to dereference your fun() in printf so that it'll give first character of string array as str gave base address which points to first character of your string.

Also, you need to give formatter as **%c** so that it'll give **H**.

Now to print whole string, you need to increment what's inside your char pointer.

See below Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* fun();

int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<6;i++){
        printf("%c",*(fun()+i));
    }
return 0;
} 

char* fun()
{
    static char str[]="Hello";
    return str;
}
```

Here you can see that I dereference fun() first to print the first character and then I made a for loop so that I can use loop variable i to increment what's inside in pointer returned by fun().

Try and let me know if you face any problem here.

Comment: "Here you want to print string so you gave %s but this fun return base address of your character array(string) but not string (as you assume)." strings in C are normally passed around as pointer to first element, and it's exactly what `printf` is expecting here; OP's code would work fine if he only provided a prototype before `fun()` (or just defined the function before `main()`).